# Коллекция из повторяющихся элементов в строке

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно составить список нужных фрагментов из строки.

```
String template = "sometext [desired text 1], ... sometext! desired text[desired text N] ..... "
```

на выходе в колекции должны остаться только

```
[desired text 1]
[desired text N]
```

т.е. только то что в ковычках.

Пока уперся в такой вариант.

```
"\\[.*?\\]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String messageText = "не нужный текст:[нужный текст],не нужный текст:[нужный текст]";
        List<String> lists= new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(messageText);
        while (m.find()) {
            lists.add(m.group());
        }
```